# iOS Xcode localisation mismatch exporting ad hoc vs debug

Tags: ios, localization, xcode5, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an iOS 7.x app with Base Italian language and specific localization for English.
When I test my build on both the terminal emulator and real devices, everything works. However, when I export as "Ad Hoc Archive" and install it on a device that uses English-only (not the base one) the localization appears independently if I switch current device i18n settings.

Why does this happen? Will the Apple Store distribution be sufficient? (I don't think so...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what is the problem.
Apple use a sort of preferred language lists that the user maintains. In my case having:

1) Base;
2) English.

and using a phone with the following preferred language list:
1) Italian;
2) English.

The phone select english as the best language for the device.
The base is reached only when no ones of the preferred language are found in the i18n list.

The only solution I found was to add another language translation specific for Italian.

Thinking better about, is correct this functionality! Why I want that a French user that selected english as 2° language see my app in Italian?

Thanks and sorry for self-responding my answer.